# How to escape the replacement string in a regex replace

Tags: regex

Say I have an input string that is something like:

{optional text} {some number} {optional text}

Where I want to replace the number.

I use the following match Regex (where 2000 is the number I want to replace):

```
^(.*)(\b2000\b)(.*)$
```

But now I am unsure how to make te replacement string. Obviously the following won't work, because it will now look for replacement 12010, which doesn't exist.

$12010$3

Is there any way I can escape the number? I've tried brackets, but they'll be present in the output. Same goes for spaces. I want the exact input with just the number replaced.

Thanks in advance.

(Oh, and I'm looking for a Regex only solution, obviously there are plenty of ways to make this work with extra string replacements or parsing the number, but those solutions are not what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the replacement number with **curly brackets**, like this

```
${1}2010$3
```

Comment: dot matches anything but line break.

Comment: @M42, right. I must have confused it with something else. Answer updated.

Comment: This was what I wanted to know, I knew there had to be some syntax to tell the parser that just the 1 belonged to the $. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
search for: \b2000\b
```

and

```
replace by: 2010
```

Comment: (psst, not sure if you flagged to migrate [this steaming pile of dung](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615856/27-ips-lcd-monitor?noredirect=1), but I think [superuser may put out a hit on you for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/migrated-question-not-marked-as-migrated-on-source-site))

Comment: Your answer absolutely works, too bad I can only flag one as the answer and Matewka's answer was what I was looking for. Thanks though!